# Django. Foreign key

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables:

Side and AdditionalCost

now **AdditionalCost** has the following foreign key field:

```
side = models.ForeignKey(Side, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='costs')
```

I want to have another foreign key field in **AdditionalCosts**:

```
number_of_additional_installations = models.ForeignKey(Side, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="number_of_additional_installations")
```

The **Side** model has the following field:

```
number_of_additional_installations = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True,
                                                             db_column='number_of_additional_installations',
                                                             verbose_name='Количество доп монтажей')
```

But I get the following error:

```
ERRORS:
<class 'kinetics.apps.address_program.admin.AdditionalCostInline'>: (admin.E202) 'address_program.AdditionalCost' has more than one ForeignKey to 'address_program.Side'.
address_program.AdditionalCost.number_of_additional_installations: (fields.E302) Reverse accessor for 'AdditionalCost.number_of_additional_installations' clashes with field name 'Side.number_of_additional_installations'.
        HINT: Rename field 'Side.number_of_additional_installations', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'AdditionalCost.number_of_additional_installations'.
address_program.AdditionalCost.number_of_additional_installations: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'AdditionalCost.number_of_additional_installations' clashes with field name 'Side.number_of_additional_installations'.
        HINT: Rename field 'Side.number_of_additional_installations', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'AdditionalCost.number_of_additional_installations'.
```

I cannot figure out why this happened because I see that code has these lines:

```
buyer_org = models.ForeignKey("acl.Organization", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                  related_name='buyer_costs')
    client_org = models.ForeignKey("acl.Organization", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                   related_name='client_costs')
```

that are obviously two foreign fields that relate to columns of one model.

If you need full code of the models let me know, it is quite large but I can add it if you need. Thank you

p.s. If I rename the related_name of number_of_additional_installations, i still get the following error:

```
ERRORS:
<class 'kinetics.apps.address_program.admin.AdditionalCostInline'>: (admin.E202) 'address_program.AdditionalCost' has more than one ForeignKey to 'address_program.Side'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you already have
`number_of_additional_installations` defined in `Sides` which clashes with the related name you set in `AdditionalCosts`. Either you rename the field in `Sides` or you change the `related_name` parameter so it wont confuse Django which field to resolve.

This code:

```
buyer_org = models.ForeignKey("acl.Organization", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                  related_name='buyer_costs')
client_org = models.ForeignKey("acl.Organization", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                   related_name='client_costs')
```

is not the same case. These fields do not cause conflict because they are referring to different relationships even if they are referring to the same model. `model.buyer_org` and `model.client_org` returns different relationships. `model.buyer_org` maps with `organization.buyer_costs` which is exclusive of `model.client_org` which, in turn, maps to `organization.client_costs`.

What's happening with the way you specify `Sides` and `AdditionalCosts` though creates conflict.

You can call `side.number_of_additional_installations` which returns an integer field but at the same time you are telling django that the `additional_costs.number_of_additional_installations` map to `side.number_of_additional_installations`.